# Angular JS calendar are not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am using the Calendar in my Angular UI which looks like

```
    <div>
        <label style="font-size: medium">To Date</label>
        <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   id="toDate"
                   name="toDate"
                   uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                   ng-model="request.toDate"
                   is-open="popup2.opened"
                   datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                   ng-required="true"
                   close-text="Close"
                   alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                   required />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
```

The calendar looks little off like below

[image]

But I am looking for something like below

[image]

I am not sure if I am missing any assembly directive here. I have the below
in my app.js

```
angular.module("app", ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngMessages')
```

and index.cshtml

```
<script src="~/Lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: can you add a plunker to your question

Comment: @supercool Never tried plunker before added the code here https://plnkr.co/edit/rV57ZedIQzztz8lwCYZd?p=preview

Comment: something like this https://plnkr.co/edit/OWuc7HGmGLmbQM7723N4?p=preview (st.from bootstrap)

Comment: Can you please tell what is changed. I am not able to follow

Comment: @supercool I did add the  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> But now the itin the picture I added in the question  looks